# SVN or CVS with Ability of Set Up Multiple Users?

Tags: svn, cvs

I'm trying to find a private website hosting service with SVN or CVS source control that enables me to set up multiple users so all of the team members in different places can log in individually and work on the same project.

It would have development features like PHP, Perl, SQL databases. Also unlimited traffic and Ruby.

Does anyone out there know how I can get this?

Thanks a million!

Comment: Are you looking for a repository host or a web app host?  Or are you trying to run both off the same account?

Answer (score 2):

I've been using http://dreamhost.com/ for years and have no complaints.

Here is a list of their features, it supports everything you require and is quite cheap: http://dreamhost.com/hosting.html

The basic package is 6$ a month, and if you feel like signing up feel free to use my referral link: http://www.dreamhost.com/r.cgi?130790 , if you don't want to use it don't worry :).

Answer (score 0):

You could consider a VPS (virtual private server)... it's like having your own server where you can install basically whatever you want. Ruby, PHP, Perl, SVN, MySQL or whatever SQL you prefer. Downsides: they're not free, although you can get an entry-level VPS (quite sufficient for many things including development) for around $20 US per month.  Also you don't get unlimited bandwidth, but that's true of any web hosting service. In practice the limits are generally high enough that you don't have to worry about hitting them. (And of course someone on your team has to know how to administer a server)

If you do decide to go this route: I'm a customer of Slicehost and I have nothing but praise for them. Linux-only though.